# How to remap : to ; in Evil Mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil

What's the Evil Mode equivalent of these Vim commands?

```
nnoremap : ;
nnoremap ; :
vnoremap : ;
vnoremap ; :
```

Comment: You might have some better luck describing what you want to do. Many people here have Emacs experience, but not Vim enough to know what those do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, in Emacs one thinks in keymaps and commands, not so much keys in their (original) context.  Your first step would be figuring out how the commands are named in Evil's normal and visual state (`F1 k`), then what keymap they're bound to (just look through `evil-maps.el` with `M-x find-library`).  Armed with this knowledge, accomplishing this is fairly simple:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd ":") 'evil-repeat-find-char)
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd ";") 'evil-ex))
```

If you for whatever reason are still on Emacs 24.3:

```
(eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  '(progn
     (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd ":") 'evil-repeat-find-char)
     (define-key evil-motion-state-map (kbd ";") 'evil-ex)))
```

You might wonder why I'm defining a remapping for motion state only, it's because Evil only maps these keys in that state, so applying your suggested changes as is would be unnecessary.

Comment: Is there a proper tutorial on making key bindings in emacs? The solution worked, but I'm still not a 100% confident on how to create my own keybindings still.

Comment: Here's an Evil-specific one: https://github.com/noctuid/evil-guide#keybindings-and-states

Comment: Hi. For some reason, I'm unable to swap the keys as such. Semi-colon now works as colon, but not the other way round. Pressing shift-; still takes me to ":" prompt. I've added the three lines as the last lines in `evil-maps.el` ... Am I missing something??

Comment: Don't edit the sources of packages, add the above snippet to your init file instead.

Comment: I've added it at `dotspacemacs/user-init` inside the dotfile, but the behaviour is still the same - both semi-colon and colon bring up the ":"